# Is there a way to overcome the 5MB storage limit on an iPhone WebApp hosted in an ObjectiveC native app?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, iphone-web-app, web-sql

We have a iPhone web application that uses WebSQL that is working fine. The amount of data downloaded depends on the user of the app. If the user has more than 5MB data, the user is prompted to increase the size of their database.

We then moved our application to run in an UIWebView hosted in a native ObjectiveC application.  The application works fine if the user stays under the 5MB database limit.  If the user has more than 5MB data, our application fails without prompting the user to increase their storage limit.

What are some alternatives to either pre-allocate the required database in the native app or somehow allow the user to be prompted to allow the database to grow to the required size?

Comment: This is for using WebSQL as a relational database, not using it for application cache.  Basically a call to a web service brings down data based upon the user of the app, that data is then stored and used in the application.

Answer (score 0):

You could write the html files to application documents directory and in database keep only the pats to the files.

Or you could use core data.

Comment: See above comment on the original question.  This is for relational data, not for the offline application cache for web assets.